# How to Add Line Break in XSLT to generate a PDF file

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I am using XSL FO (1.0) to generate a PDF file Below is the xml and xslt for that.. I want to add line break in xslt

XML

```
    <catalog>
    <cd value="First">
        <title company="Grammy" price="10.20">1999 Grammy Nominees</title>
        <artist all="type">Many</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
    </cd>
    </catalog>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="catalog/cd">
<fo:block>
    <xsl:value-of select="title " />
    <xsl:value-of select="artist" />
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Getting "1999 Grammy NomineesMany" as Output.How to add Line break to get the below output

```
1999 Grammy Nominees
Many
```

Thanks!!

Comment: The `xsl:apply-templates` will process `title` and `artist` and also `country`. What happens then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add `<fo:block/>` between the two `xsl:value-of` or put each `xsl:value-of` in a separate `fo:block`.